# How to fix Go 1.11 module unknown import path, cannot find module providing package?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am building a Go 1.11 Standard App Engine Service.

It's not under `GOPATH`, so I ran `go mod init` and `go mod tidy`.

I am able to build a simple web service using `go build`, and deploy and test using `gcloud app deploy`.

I am now trying to add gPubSub code to my service following [this code example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/pubsub/pubsub_quickstart/main.go).

This adds the following imports: `"context"`, `"cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"`.

When I run `go build`, I get:

```
../../../../go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20181217023233-e147a9138326/idna/idna.go:23:2: unknown import path "golang.org/x/text/secure/bidirule": cannot find module providing package golang.org/x/text/secure/bidirule
../../../../go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20181217023233-e147a9138326/idna/idna.go:24:2: unknown import path "golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi": cannot find module providing package golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi
../../../../go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20181217023233-e147a9138326/idna/idna.go:25:2: unknown import path "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm": cannot find module providing package golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm
```

When I run `go get -u all`, I get "no Go files in"

```
go build golang.org/x/text/secure/bidirule: no Go files in
go build golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi: no Go files in
go build golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm: no Go files in
```

`cat go.mod` shows me the following:
```

```
module github.com/XXX/YYY

require (
    cloud.google.com/go v0.34.0
    github.com/googleapis/gax-go v2.0.2+incompatible // indirect
    go.opencensus.io v0.18.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20181217023233-e147a9138326 // indirect
    golang.org/x/oauth2 v0.0.0-20181203162652-d668ce993890 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20181108010431-42b317875d0f // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20181218192612-074acd46bca6 // indirect
    google.golang.org/api v0.0.0-20181220000619-583d854617af // indirect
    google.golang.org/appengine v1.3.0 // indirect
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20181219182458-5a97ab628bfb // indirect
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.17.0 // indirect
)
```

```

`go list .` shows me the following:

```
go: finding golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi latest
go: finding golang.org/x/text/secure/bidirule latest
go: finding golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm latest
go: finding golang.org/x/text/unicode latest
go: finding golang.org/x/text/secure latest
github.com/XXX/YYY/ZZZ (our project)
```

This seems to be some transient dependency.

When I deploy using `gcloud app deploy`, my service *does* successfully build and on execution, publishes to the pubsub topic, so this is a local problem.

How do I diagnose and fix this local dev environment problem?

Comment: uhh don't you just need to go get golang.org/x/package/name then import "package/name"

Comment: @luminoslty `go get golang.org/x/text` was the first thing I tried - had no effect

Comment: This looks like `go get` was interrupted in the past, and left empty directories in `$HOME/go/pkg/mod` (the module cache). What happens if you delete `$HOME/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text*` and run `go build` again?

Comment: thanks @Peter - that looks to have solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

fixed:

`rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.0`

`go get golang.org/x/text`

Comment: Thanks a ton! This worked with an issue I had with `firestore` and `../../go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.24.0`